# How to know the code changed at which version?

Tags: svn

I want to know is anyway to know the a function or a piece of code at what time(version).

in my company, we often use subversion to maintain our project.

one time , I used winmerge to diff the same code at different version. 
however the range of version maybe very huge.
maybe,
version A r113
version B r2323455

and I got a section changed, I want to know the section change at what version.
maybe at r1244 or r2454 
I couldn't find it manually, is there anyway to fix the hard problem.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use [svn blame](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html). If you're using tortoise svn, right click the file -> tortoise svn - blame

Comment: Please link to actual version of SVNBook (1.7 so far), not to outdated 1.5.